# Definition of unconditional stability for Numerical schemes (PDEs)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am studying numerical schemes for partial differential equations, and I find frequently the expression "unconditionally stable".

They always prove unconditional stability using Von Neumann technique, but I did not find a definition of what is exactly unconditional stability. In some PDFs they say that it means that the numerical scheme does not diverge, in others it says that it means that if the continuous-time model is stable then the discrete-time one is also stable, ... It seems like there is not a unique definition ?